# C++ Removing shared_ptr from 2 different vectors

Tags: c++

I'm not sure is it possible to use same iterator that points to shared_ptr and use that to delete same shared_ptr from two different vectors?

---

I mean if I get iterator like this:

```
auto stop = std::find_if(stops_.begin(), stops_.end(),
                             [=](const std::shared_ptr<Stop>& stop){return id == stop->id_;});
```

I can't use it to erase from 2 different containers

```
stops_.erase(stop);
region->get()->stops_.erase(stop);
```

Comment: No, an iterator that points to a vector cannot be used to operate on another, unrelated vector.

Comment: @Vex It is unclear what you mean saying about the same iterator.

Comment: Are you sure you mean the same shared_ptr and not a completely different shared_ptr that happens to point to the same object? If you have `int a = 2; int b = 2;` they are in no sense the "same int", right? They just happen to have the same value.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Check below, sorry that I made a bit unclear :s

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Check below, I didn't mean it like that. I should have included code at first point :/

Comment: Well I should have used std::remove with erase so that was the problem why it doesn't work

Comment: Ahh, so what you're asking is if you can use the same iterator to remove two different shared pointers that point to the same object.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Exactly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. An iterator of a standard container can only be used to point to an element of one container. Passing an iterator of one instance into a member function of another instance results in undefined behaviour. You need separate iterators.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use an iterator from one container to refer to an element in another container.

What you would have to do is dereference the iterator to get the actual `shared_ptr` object itself, and then you can look for that object in the other container.  For example:

```cpp
auto iter = ...; // iterator in vector1
std::remove(vector2.begin(), vector2.end(), *iter);
```

This would work since `std::shared_ptr` implements `operator==` to compare whether 2 `shared_ptr`s are pointing at (sharing) the same object pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have the same object in two different vectors. Each vector owns all of the objects in that vector..